# JPA Specifications GroupBy

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, group-by, spring-data-jpa

I need a help with performing groupby for a single table using JPA Specifications.

| customerid | customername | purchaseproductid | purchasedate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sam | 002 | 02.03.2021 |
| 3 | Joe | 005 | 05.03.2021 |
| 1 | Sam | 014 | 07.06.2021 |
| 2 | Britney | 015 | 10.07.2021 |

I want to select the customername, count(purchaseproductid), purchasedate and order them to purchasedate

Using JPA specification

Here is my code in Specification

public Specification filterCustomerPurchases(FilterParams filterParams,
SortParams sortParams) {

```
    return (final Root<ItemConversions> root, final CriteriaQuery<?> cq, final CriteriaBuilder cb) -> {
        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();



        if (filterParams.purchaseProductId() != null && !filterParams.purchaseProductId().isEmpty()) {
             predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("purchaseProductId"), filterParams.purchaseProductId()));
        }

        if (filterParams.purchaseCustomerName() != null && !filterParams.purchaseCustomerName().isEmpty()) {
                        predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("purchaseCustomerName"), filterParams.purchaseCustomerName()));
                    }

        if (sortParams.getAsc() != null) {
            sortParams.getAsc().forEach(param -> {
                if (param != null && !param.isEmpty()) {
                    cq.orderBy(cb.asc(root.get(param)));
                }
            });
        }
        if (sortParams.getDesc() != null) {
            sortParams.getDesc().forEach(param -> {
                if (param != null && !param.isEmpty()) {
                    cq.orderBy(cb.desc(root.get(param)));
                }
            });
        }

        return cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
    };

}
```

I am calling this inside a service

customerPurcasesRepository.findAll(cutomerSpesifications.filterCustomerPurchases(filterParams, sortParams));

I want to do filterting + sorting + groupby(customerId)

Comment: Can you share some code on what you have tried so far? Also sharing your Entity classes etc would be helpful for other members wishing to help you.

Comment: @pleft I have updated the question with my code so far. Want to do the filtering+sorting+ grouping together.

Answer (score 0):

Specifications are intended to encode where clauses. They are not suited for doing Group By or similar. You'd need to write your own custom method.

Comment: I have added the sample code with the question. Can you help to find the way to do the grouping together with all.